# Why is "the expenditure" wrong?

Tags: definite-article

Why shouldn't we use the definite article with an uncountable noun to refer to the thing we already mentioned. Take for example the sentence below. If we don't use "**the** expenditure", how can others know that we're referring to expenditure on the housing project in the first sentence? I know "expenditure" is correct and "**the** expenditure" is incorrect? But why?

> The government spent $2 million dollars on the housing project last
> year. **Expenditure** increased to $3 million this year.

Comment: Are you sure that "The expenditure increased.." is incorrect? I googled in Google Books, and it has instances of "the expenditure increased".

Comment: At least "expenditure" is better than "the expenditure". I got my essay checked by a native speaker. He removed the definite article before "expenditure".

Comment: A very interesting question. I hope someone answers it.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the use of the definite article at the start of the second sentence. It's perfectly grammatical. Most people would omit it because it's unnecessary. It's elided. Readers understand that **expenditure** in the second sentence refers to the spending on the housing project. A similar example might be: **The plane's departure has been delayed; departure will now be at midday.**

Comment: It's grammatical. But it's probably not idiomatic to say "the expenditure" and "the departure", isn't it?

Comment: "Expenditure" is worse, not better, than "the expenditure." "Expenditures" would also be idiomatic, as stupid as that sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I would typically use the article. There's nothing wrong with saying:

> **The expenditure** increased to $3 million this year.

Not using the article sounds awkward to me. To omit the article, I would reference it in a more generic way:

> **Expenditures** increased to $3 million this year.

Comment: Thank you. Then how can you explain this one: 30% of households owned a house in 1968. Ownership increased to 50% in 1998. I think it should be "ownership", not "the ownership" or "ownerships".

Comment: I dreamed up that ownership sentence, but I remember that a native speaker taught me to use it without the definite article.

Comment: It's the same as my second example that uses Expenditures. Ownership is also plural.